# APA6 one author latex citation doesn't work

Tags: latex, pdflatex, bibtex

```latex
\documentclass[jou,apacite]{apa6}

\title{Example of an APA style for journal article}
\shorttitle{APA style}

\twoauthors{Author One}{Author Two}
\twoaffiliations{Institute of Psychology}{Institute of Psychology}

\rightheader{APA style}
\leftheader{Author One}

\begin{document}
\maketitle    

\section{Sample section}
Sample text \cite{Nag2018}  \cite{gueguen2003effect} 

\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

If I write the above LaTeX apa code, it gives output like this:

> Sample text (Nag, Mondal, & More, 2018) (Gueguen & De Gail, 2003)

But I want only one author name and year in the the output, such as:

> (Nag,2018)

How can I do this?? I do not want all authors name.

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that in particular includes the bib entries necessary to compile your document?